# AngularJS 1.x: Dynamically created multiple File Upload fields

Tags: angularjs

You have to excuse me, I do not use Angular that often. I need to implement a solution in which I can upload files from dynamically generated input fields.

***The catch is that I cannot use any directives*** (this is due to the framework I am using in which AngularJS is implemented).

My current code for creating fields:

```
$scope.addNewFile = function() {
    var newFileNo = $scope.files.length + 1;
    $scope.files.push({'id': 'file' + newFileNo});
};

$scope.removeFile = function() {
    var lastFile = $scope.files.length - 1;
    $scope.files.splice(lastFile);
};
```

And here is the code for uploading files (not correct, because of static `id` and `name` values:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function() {
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader;
    r.onloadend = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        console.log('data');
        console.log(data);
        // http.post
    };
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
};
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="file in files">
    <div class="row top-buffer">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input type="file"
                   ng-model="file.name"
                   name="file"
                   class="form-control"
                   id="file">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 text-right">
            <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="uploadFile()">Upload</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row top-buffer">
    <div class="col-lg-11"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 text-right">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="addNewFile()"></div>
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="removeFile()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't really understand how I can get the values of dynamically generated file fields... any help appreciated!

Comment: No `ng-repeat`?  And why can you not use directives?  That seems like a bad use of one or both frameworks.

Comment: I understand that. But that is due to how the other framework is built... So I need to find a solution.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with the file.  Do you need the actual file contents in javascript?  Why not just use `formData` when you POST to your server?

Comment: I need to get the file in order to $http.post it after :). Actually all the files, which were dynamically added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ng-model` for `<input type=file`, but you can achieve what you want setting the `id` dynamically with `ng-attr`:

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files">
  {{file.id}}:
  <input type="file"
         ng-attr-name="{{file.id}}"
         ng-attr-id="{{file.id}}">
</div>
```

On `uploadFile()` you can post them:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function() {
  $scope.files.forEach(function(file) {
    // $http.post: document.getElementById(file.id).files[0])
  });
};
```

Example on Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/virgilioafonsojr/92nw4j4f/1/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Writing an uploader properly is a very difficult task. A major problem with an upload component/directive is getting it to work in Internet Explorer; because it can only be used once in IE. Another problem is that IE will not let you programmatically "press" the button, it must be a real mouse click.

There are upload libraries out there for AngularJs, just google. However if you are intent on doing it yourself then you can use my git repo as an example of how it should be done. Just use the jwtUploader and jwtUploaderButton directives.

https://github.com/smylydon/SEPE-7WCM0033-0206-FRONTEND/tree/master/client/app

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but as I mentioned before I cannot use custom directives, unfortunately.